# How to render js rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a vote model with "like", "dislike" actions. I have a route for each of these actions. When I call the actions, I'm returning a json response. My problem is that first, I need to figure out how to send the query to my like/dislike actions. I need to access ruby/rails variables from my javascript (I'm sending an ajax request using jquery's $.getJSON), so that for example I can create the request for the correct item. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A popular technique is to attach data to the dom. For example (pseudocode follows):

```
<% items.each do |item| %>
  <div class="like_button" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">Like</div>
<% end %>
```

and in the JavaScript:

```
$(".like_button").on("click", function() {
  var item_id = $(this).data('item-id'); // from the dom
  // construct Ajax request for item_id
});
```

Comment: Brandon, thank you. I started like this: **link_to "like", "path_to_json", :remote => true, :method => :post**, then I respond with like.js to update the dom. Your method seems cleaner, while not using rails built in *:remote*. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tend to prefer using `form_for ... remote: true` when I can (and when it makes sense, usually for updating resources), and binding to the Rails `ajax:success`, et al. from JavaScript. Great writeup: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Comment: Brandon, thanks for the update. This does a lot for a rails newbie. Thanks for the link too. Its all clear now. Cheers.